# TypeError: int() argument must be a string... not 'NonType'

Tags: python, pandas

I have data that looks like this in a DataFrame called items:

```
     Yr     Mo  Count
1   2008    2   14
2   2008    3   37
3   2008    4   23
4   2008    5   22
5   2008    6   32
6   2008    7   45
7   2008    8   33
8   2008    9   24
9   2008    10  70
10  2008    11  48
11  2008    12  60
12  2009    1   63
13  2009    2   64
14  2009    3   60
15  2009    4   63
16  2009    5   41
17  2009    6   44
18  2009    7   42
19  2009    8   47
20  2009    9   57
21  2009    10  62
22  2009    11  47
23  2009    12  50
```

I am trying to apply a function using groupby.transform and have the function be applied by the 'Yr' column.
The function I am trying to apply is below:

```
def normal (list):
    for item in list:
        mn = min(list)
        mx = max(list)
        (item-mn)/(mx-mn)
```

The line of code I am trying to use for the groupby.transform is this:

```
import pandas as pd
appts2['normal'] = appts2.groupby('Yr')['Count'].transform(normal)
```

The following is the traceback that I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-49-6f01ec40e613>", line 1, in <module>
    appts2['Normal'] = appts2.groupby('Yr')['Count'].transform(normal)

  File "file location", line 2845, in transform
    result[indexer] = res

TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'NoneType'
```

Comment: Maybe you forgot a `return` statement somewhere? That's a common source of unexpected `None`s.

Comment: If I put a return in the for statement then the function will run in the groupby.transform but it only returns the result for the first row instead of applying it to each row

Comment: You have to dedent it it must start the same column as the `for` statement not the body.

Comment: Doing that I still get the same TypeError I have with my initial question

Comment: Just to be sure you do `return` something? A `return` statemnt without return value returns `None`.

Answer (score 0):

Paul Panzer thank you for the help,

I changed the function to this and it is now working properly:

```
def normal (list):
    mn = min(list)
    mx = max(list)
    result=[]
    for item in list:
        result.append((item-mn)/(mx-mn))
    result = pd.Series(result)
    return result
```